# Create a trigger or a constraint to filer duplicate data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, constraints

How to create a trigger or a constraint to filter the duplicate data that are going to be input into the database afterward.
The duplicate means both the **sensor_id** and **time** are the same.

For example, now the table is

```
rain_gage   sensor_id   time
2.434       6000        2017-07-24 14:23:55
5.324       6010        2017-07-24 09:12:22
```

Now I insert the new data to the table through Spring boot's repository.

```
rain_gage   sensor_id   time
2.434       6000        2017-07-24 14:23:55
5.324       6010        2017-07-24 10:23:19
```

I want the trigger or the constraint filter the row (2.434, 6000, 2017-07-24 14:23:55).

Then the table will be

```
rain_gage   sensor_id   time
2.434       6000        2017-07-24 14:23:55
5.324       6010        2017-07-24 09:12:22
5.324       6010        2017-07-24 10:23:19
```

BTW, I use MySQL database.

Comment: Give it a try first, you'll probably just get downvoted here otherwise

Comment: what about a `UNIQUE` constraint?

Comment: Yes, it could be. Could you post a code segment, I'm really a newbie in database.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is already created, it needs to be altered to add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the required fields.

```
ALTER TABLE <Table-Name> ADD CONSTRAINT <Constraint-Name> UNIQUE (SENSOR_ID, TIME);
```

The `UNIQUE` constraint can also be added at the time of table creation.

```
CREATE TABLE <Table-Name> (
    ....
    CONSTRAINT <Constraint-Name> UNIQUE (SENSOR_ID, TIME)
);
```

This will ensure only unique records get inserted. Any exceptions that occur for duplicate records will have to handled gracefully.